# Error in t(partial) %*% vcov : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments

Tags: r, error-handling, compiler-errors

I am analysing a mark-recpature distance sampling (mrds) project.
I have run a loop to obtain to fit the best covariate to the mr model. I am now attempting to run a loop to analyse the covariates in the ds model with the best fit mr model.

the code is:

```
ds.formula <- c("~size","~team","~Region.Label","~side","size+side","~size+team",
                "~size+Region.Label","~size+team+Region.Label","~side+Region.Label","~side+team",
                "~side+Region.Label+team","~size+Region.Label+side",
                "~size+team+Region.Label+side")
num.ds.models <- length(ds.formula)

##dataframe to store results is:
pi.results <- data.frame(DSmodel=ds.formula, AIC=rep(NA,num.ds.models))

##loop through ds models with selected mr model
for (i in 1:num.ds.models) {
  pi.model <- ddf(method='io', mrmodel=~glm(link='logit',formula=~distance*size+Region.Label+team),
                  dsmodel=~mcds(key='hn',formula=as.formula(ds.formula[i])), 
                  data=animal, meta.data=list(width=300))
  pi.results$AIC[i] <- summary(pi.model)$AIC
}
```

Though I get the error in the title of this thread:
Error in t(partial) %*% vcov : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments

How do i resolve this issue.
Do i need to somehow change the code:

```
pi.results <- data.frame(DSmodel=ds.formula, AIC=rep(NA,num.ds.models))
```

to include a matrix? If so How do I structure this? As I have attempted to add matrix () in after the data.frame. But that only leads to a unused argument error.

Comment: I am not sure it is a matrix issue. but possibly a vector or numeric issue. Though I am unable to see what is causing the issue.